# OData filtering nested result fails

Tags: filter, sharepoint, odata, azure-logic-apps

Currently I'm working with a LogicApp & Filters (oData).
My goal is to provide data inside the LogicApp from the Sharepoint-List. The column inside the Sharepoint-List is a 'LookUp'. So this means I get a nested Result.
I did my research and found out that it's possible to iterate trough nested blocks with an `"/"`.

As an Example:

```
$filter=ProductionStation/ProductionUnit eq '@{triggerOutputs()['queries']['searchKey']}'
```

But this somehow gives me an error.

Comment: `'@{triggerOutputs()['queries']['searchKey']}'` is not a valid string literal, you must double the quotes inside: `'@{triggerOutputs()[''queries'']['searchKey'']}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error due to wrong expression i.e., `@{triggerOutputs()['queries']['searchKey']}`. After reproducing from our end, we could able to make this work using the below expression.

```
@triggerOutputs()?['queries']?['searchKey']
```